# How to convert an arraylist to hashmap handling duplicates using Java8 Streams API?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have an arraylist of the following model class:

```
public class EnvironmentVariable {

    private String key;
    private String value;

    public EnvironmentVariable() {}

    public EnvironmentVariable(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I want to convert it to a `Hashmap`. I know the straight-forward method of iterating over the list, but I am more interested in using the Java 8 streams API while handling the duplicates in the key value. How can I handle the duplicates?

Edit: I tried the following till now.

```
Map<String, User> map = 
    list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(EnvironmentVariable::getKey, EnvironmentVariable::getValue));
```

In case of duplicates, I'd like to return the older (first encountered) value.

Comment: "How can I handle the duplicates?" What do you mean?

Comment: @GhostCat, the second one, when available.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: @MadPhysicist Did I overlook that? Where is that in the question?

Comment: @GhostCat, I have updated the question with details.

Comment: @Rob read the javadoc of the method you're using, and that I linked to. It says: *If the mapped keys may have duplicates, use toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator) instead*. So, use that method, and pass a BinaryOperator that returns the older, first encountered value. Everything becomes much easier when you read the documentation.

Comment: @GhostCat. Sorry, I was just giving a ridiculous option. Forgot to put ":)"